# Why openssl on windows produces error but not on centos: PKCS12_parse: mac verify failure (OpenSSL::PKCS12::PKCS12Error)

Tags: ruby, openssl

```
require 'openssl'

if ARGV.length == 2
    pkcs12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(ARGV[0]), ARGV[1])
    p pkcs12.certificate
else
    puts "Usage: load_cert.rb <path_to_cert> <cert_password>"
end
```

Running this produces error on windows but not in linux.

**Error:**

> OpenSSL::PKCS12::PKCS12Error: PKCS12_parse: mac verify failure
>           from (irb):21:in `initialize`
>           from (irb):21:in `new`
>           from (irb):21
>           from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>`

Comment: Based on your answer, you should file a Bug with the Ruby project. If it got you, it will get others. Ruby cannot fix it unless they know about it. See [Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
File.read("UserCert.p12", "rb")
```

Problem was ruby by default read file as text and need to force to read file as binary, it solves the problem

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, but the following did `File.binread('UserCert.p12')`

Comment: it depends which ruby version your using,  is it happening ruby 1.9.2 ?

Comment: i'm using ruby 2.0.0p353

Comment: Then it could be different, as this was for 1.9.2

Comment: Which is why I mentioned it :)